# git --git-dir not working in windows

Tags: git, msysgit

In a hook script for Git, I am trying to run a command like this..

please refer to([git --git-dir not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected))

```
git log --name-status --git-dir="C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CMS\.git" --work-tree="C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CMS"
```

when I run this command I am getting the following error.

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Is there any thing wrong in the command I am using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a **hook script**, it will probably use [POSIX paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Posix_pathname_definition), in a bash session, not Windows paths.

```
git log --name-status --git-dir='/C/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/CMS/.git' --work-tree='/C/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/CMS'
```

---

From a DOS session (as in "not a hook), the path might have looked like:

```
git log --name-status --git-dir='C:/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/CMS/.git' --work-tree='C:/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/CMS'
```

Alternative syntax (not tested): `"c:\\xxx\\yyy\\..."`

Comment: @Syam: I have updated my answer with POSIX path. Give it a try.

Answer (score 8):

I recently had this problem on Mac, the solution for me was to put the --git-dir and --work-tree directives before the git subcommand.

So, your command would look like this:

```
git --git-dir="C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CMS\.git" --work-tree="C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CMS" log --name-status
```

HTH, it did the trick for me.

Comment: It's odd that it works for anyone with it *after*. `--git-dir` is an option for `git`, not for `log`.

Comment: Thanks it solves the problem on Windows also: `"c:\program files (x86)\git\bin\git.exe" --git-dir="c:/path/to/repo/.git" --work-tree="c:/path/to/repo" commit -m"Message" c:\path\to\repo\file.test`