# Why does Xcode 4 continually display "Checking source control status" for a git repository?

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4

When I open my project which has a git repo, Xcode continually displays "Checking source control status" at the top of the window. My git repo is working find and I am able to commit changes to it using the command line utility.

Why am I seeing this message? Furthermore, is there any way to get rid of it? I would like to rename my Xcode project, but with this issue, I can't. When trying to rename the project, Xcode gives the error: The operation could not be performed because the repository could not be reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One workaround, if you don't want to have any interaction with Git in your XCode project would be to **move the `.git` directory elsewhere**.

You can still perform any git operation you want from a shell, with the [environment variable `GIT_DIR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally/1753078#1753078) set to the external path where the `.git` has been moved (or adding the [option `--git-dir=/path/to/external/.git`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected/1386350#1386350) to any of your git commands).

But XCode shouldn't be aware of that external .git and shouldn't try to contact a repo anymore, allowing you to perform any XCode operation you want, like renaming the XCode project.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4.0 has many great ideas with much half-baked implementation. It's exciting for the future of the tool, and sad for the present. Hopefully 4.3, which will be the next release to coincide with iOS 5 and Lion, will resolve this sort of thing--the docs do talk about addressing some of Xcode's inadequacies w/r/t git.

In the current version, Xcode's interaction with git is so hobbled as to be useless. I started trying to use it and gave up. My advice is, just don't go into the repositories section of the organizer window and continue interacting with your repo on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help with not being able to rename the project.

Comment: I'm saying: It's broken. I can't rename, remove, or really do anything useful with a git repo from Xcode. Worse, it auto-adds every modification, preventing the whole idea of atomic commits.

Comment: I don't want to do anything with the git repo in Xcode. I want to rename the Xcode project. Sorry if I wasn't clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences in XCODE , select the Source Control TAB and uncheck the "Enable Source Control" button