# Main Project in SVN, submodule from GitHub, how do best go about that to preserve updatability?

Tags: xcode, svn, git, git-svn

I have a main project on my person SVN server and I have one of more components that are in GIT remote repositories. Is there a way to set it up such that setting it all up that Xcode 4 can deal with this use of two different technologies but still allow me to update either way?

Or if this cannot be done compatibly with Xcode what is the most convenient manual approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the current level of integration with Git from XCode (as illustrated by the SO question "[Why does Xcode 4 continually display “Checking source control status” for a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267762/why-does-xcode-4-continually-display-checking-source-control-status-for-a-git-r/6294719#6294719)"), I would really recommend keeping all Git-related operations in a separate shell.

If you have code in an SVN server, try to setup that integration first, then update your local Git repo manually and add references to those path from your XCode project.

Comment: can the local git repo be in the project folder? Or should I rather have that in parallel and only have a reference from my Xcode project to these files?

Comment: @Cocoanetics: The link I mention in my answer is precisely for *avoiding* any `.git` within the XCode project folder. That doesn't mean you cannot checkout a Git repo in that folder, only that the `.git` repo itself should be elsewhere, outside of XCode project.