# git pull for a local repository at specified location (instead of pwd)

Tags: git

`pwd` is "present working directory". Here's the situation.

```
pwd:            /path/to/pwd/
git repository: /repo/path/.git/
```

I want to do a git pull from origin, but without changing my current directory.

To clarify just a little more in case I'm not clear enough, this is the result I want, but I want to do it with one command instead of having to change directories:

```
$ cd /repo/path
$ git pull origin master
$ cd -
```

Comment: What's the use case for this? (I'm just curious.)

Comment: @KajMagnus This was over 5 years ago, I honestly can't remember. Probably something like wanting to update the repo with a one-liner so I could use `^r` to run it repeatedly as needed, and without messing up the directory stack because I frequently use `pushd`, `popd`, and `cd -`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git --git-dir not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
git --work-tree=/repo/path --git-dir=/repo/path/.git pull origin master
```

Comment: This is pretty difficult to apply as it stands. Can you provide an example with a public repo?

Comment: @Cognitiaclaeves, not sure what you mean by "difficult to apply"? Just tried it and it "just worked". It should work with any repo you have access too public or not.

Comment: Yes as of 2022 you still have to specify the .git location and the work tree path, somewhat as annoying as having to cd in and out. Might as well use `cd /repo/path && git pull && cd /current/path`

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau If you're doing it that way you could use `pushd /repo/path; git pull; popd`, or the old `cd /repo/path; git pull; cd -` so that you don't have to mess about with remembering or typing your working directory.

Answer (score 4):

bash -c "cd /repo/path; git pull origin master"

Comment: Is there really no git option for this? Git is exploding with functionality, it seems hard to believe you MUST have your working directory in repository location or subdirectory of it.

Comment: Oh, I have no idea.  If there is a way I'm all ears! :)  I just wanted to give you a one-liner.

Comment: no need for `bash -c`, you can use `(list)` to execute list in a subshell: `(cd /repo/path; git pull origin master)`