# How can I git add a file without changing the current working directory?

Tags: git

I want to add and commit a file in git without changing my current working directory.  Is this possible?

```
> pwd
/tmp 

> git --git-dir=/tmp/git_test/.git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/git_test/.git/

> ls /tmp/git_test
commit1

> git --git-dir=/tmp/git_test/.git add /tmp/git_test/commit1
fatal: '/tmp/git_test/commit1' is outside repository

> git --git-dir=/tmp/git_test/.git add commit1
fatal: pathspec 'commit1' did not match any files
```

(git add -A seems to use the current working directory, rather than the argument to --git-dir)

Comment: It may be "cheating", but running `(cd /tmp/git-test; git add commit1)` will leave your outer shell in the same directory it had been before spawning the subshell which runs everything within `(...)`.

Comment: Answered elsewhere on Stack Overflow:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 13):

You missed an option: `--work-tree`. If you're outside the repository, you need to supply both that and `--git-dir`:

> `--work-tree=<path>`
>
> Set the path to the working tree. It can be an absolute path or a path relative to the current working directory. This can also be controlled by setting the GIT_WORK_TREE environment variable and the core.worktree configuration variable (see core.worktree in git-config(1) for a more detailed discussion).

Comment: if this is the right answer, please give @Jefromi the credit and mark ("check") it as the correct answer.

Comment: @FlakDiNenno Educating new users is certainly good, but this question is two years old and the OP hasn't been seen in a year and a half.