# Xcode git add file not in current directory

Tags: xcode, git

I'm using Xcode 4's built-in Git functionality, and I am pushing my commits to a remote repository.

However, the code files are in one directory `(~/users/me/projects/theproject)` and the images are in a second, separate directory. `(~/dropbox/projects/theproject)`. Xcode thus allows me to add, commit, and push files that I place in the first directory, but not in the second one. If I right-click one of files, then do Source Control -> Add, it's greyed out.

How can I add the files in the second directory in the remote repository? Is it possible to do it within Xcode? If not, what would be the git command?

Comment: please see my answer below about "creating a **junction** or **hardlink**" - this will allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Files in a single git repository need to be part of the same directory tree (that is, they all need to be located somewhere underneath the directory containing the `.git` directory).  If you were to move your images from `~/dropbox/...` into `~/users/me/projects/theproject`, you would be able to add them to the repository.

Alternatively, you could create a separate repository inside your `dropbox` folder and use that just for the images.

Comment: I can't move the files as there are hundreds of them and I would need to manually readd them to the target. Changing the git directory is possible to do from the command line (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797387/how-can-i-git-add-a-file-without-changing-the-current-working-directory) but I can't figure out the command...

Answer (score 1):

I do this exact thing by creating a **junction** or **hardlink** (*see below*) to my "directory that's outside of the tree" so that it appears to be mounted inside the directory hierarchy where my .git folder/repo sits.

like so:

```
\(root of project)            <------ \real_images_folder
 |-- .git                     |   
 |-- htdocs                   |
 |-- images  <------junction---
```

---

#### see my answer here for details on how to create a junction:   https://superuser.com/questions/455853/can-i-delete-the-the-folder-c-programdata-package-cache?answertab=active#tab-top