# Git pulling depends on the current dir

Tags: git, git-pull

I am trying to `git pull` some repository via root user from any directory.

For example, executing `git pull` from `/root/`:

```
#> cd ~
#> sudo -u dmalikov git --git-dir=/home/dmalikov/path/to/repo/.git pull 
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 142: cd: /root/.: Permission denied
Cannot chdir to /root/., the toplevel of the working tree
```

And executing `git pull` from `/`:

```
#> cd /
#> sudo -u dmalikov git --git-dir=/home/dmalikov/path/to/repo/.git pull 
Already up-to-date.
```

Why did current directory affects `git pull`ing command?

How can that redundant `cd` be avoided?

Comment: Where is /root is it a folder inside your repo? If it is you shouldn't have permission issues.

If /root is outside of your git structure, the question that begs to be asked is why is it accessing that folder in the first place?

Comment: Why are you trying to work as root?

Comment: I am trying to work with root because it is a content of eix-sync.conf.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your first example, the git command runs as user `dmalikov` with the current directory `/root`. Since the `git pull` command is equivalent to a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`, and since `git merge` operates on the working tree, git tries to hunt for the working tree. As this user does not have permission to `cd /root`, the git command fails.

Even your second example doesn't work as you would expect. If there are actual changes to be pulled (instead of "Already up-to-date"), then the `git pull` will fail because it can't find the working tree.

You have a few simple options:

1) You can just do the `git fetch` portion of the operation by doing:

```
sudo -u dmalikov git --git-dir=/home/dmalikov/path/to/repo/.git fetch
```

which doesn't give any error for me.

2) You can add a `cd` to the working tree:

```
(cd /home/dmalikov/path/to/repo; sudo -u dmalikov git pull)
```

Comment: Related: git --git-dir not working as expected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own comment, the /root was an interesting error

To have it work with --git-dir you also need to specify a work-tree directory

```
sudo -u dmalikov git --git-dir=/home/dmalikov/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/home/dmalikov/path/to/repo/.git pull
```

Comment: `fatal: Could not change back to '/root': Permission denied`

Comment: What machine are you on? It will use your system (windows or linux) specific paths.

The following works on my local machine (git bash on windows)
`$ git --git-dir=/c/workspace/changes/.git --work-tree=/c/workspace/changes/ pull
Already up-to-date.`

Comment: Try to execute your command from dir, where you cannot `cd` via non-root user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to avoid that cd as you run git with a user that doesn't have permission to change directory back to the current directory, i.e. /root. / as current directory obviously works since everyone has permissions to change to that directory.

Comment: `fatal: Could not change back to '/root': Permission denied`

Comment: Changed my answer. It has to do with permissions and not --work-tree as I thought initially.