# Git pull in "remote" directory

Tags: git

In Git you can clone a given directory to given directory:

```
git clone ssh://gitolite@dev.bipper.com:3687/com/bipper/kids/portal <dir>
```

Cause of some intricate issues with "cd" command when I run one of our build scripts I would like to take git pull something like this:

```
git pull <dir-to-the-git-folder>
```

Ergo not having to be in the git folder when executing the pull (or fetch/merge) when doing so, is it possible to achieve somehow (my above example doesn't work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should have a look at the `git-dir` and perhaps also `work-tree` options. You can also use the `GIT_DIR` / `GIT_WORK_TREE` variables if you prefer to.

See the manual :

> `--git-dir=<path>` 
>   Set the path to the repository. This can also be controlled by setting the GIT_DIR environment variable. It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory.
>
> `-work-tree=<path>`
>              Set the path to the working tree. It can be an absolute path or a path relative to the current working directory. This can also be controlled by setting the GIT_WORK_TREE environment variable and the
>              core.worktree configuration variable (see core.worktree in git-config(1) for a more detailed discussion).

Comment: hmm, btw, trying to this on our linux server

git --git-dir=/tmp/deployment_1347960691855 --work-tree=/tmp/deployment_1347960691855 pull

But get
WARN:fatal: Not a git repository: '/tmp/deployment_1347960691855'

But it is a Git repo

Comment: Also tried locally on my Windows machine with an other Git project I have:

C:\>git --git-dir=C:\projectsGit\bsafe-server --work-tree=C:\projectsGit\bsafe-server  pull
fatal: Not a git repository: 'C:\projectsGit\bsafe-server'

Comment: Maybe you should try `C:\projectsGit\basfe-server\.git` for the git-dir option... see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected Not what the manual says, though...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
GIT_DIR=<dir-to-the-git-folder>/.git GIT_WORK_TREE=<dir-to-the-git-folder> git pull
```

You can also specify these options using `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` respectively.

From `man git`:

> ```
>    --git-dir=<path>
>        Set the path to the repository. This can also be controlled by setting the GIT_DIR environment
>        variable. It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory.
>
>    --work-tree=<path>
>        Set the path to the working tree. It can be an absolute path or a path relative to the current
>        working directory. This can also be controlled by setting the GIT_WORK_TREE environment variable
>        and the core.worktree configuration variable (see core.worktree in git-config(1) for a more
>        detailed discussion).
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As of git 1.8.5 you can use the `-C` option to change the dir context.

```
sudo -u www-data -H git -C /var/www/ status
```

`-H` will set the home-dir for your command. It is optional, but usefull when you want to avoid the following errors:

```
warning: unable to access '/root/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
or
warning: unable to access '/home/user/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
```