# Get Git repo url using absolute path

Tags: git, bash, shell, terminal

I can get the repository path running the following command in the repository folder (like it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090938/1420197)):

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

How can I get the git repository url using an absolute path?

Suppose that I am in another folder and I want to get the repository url from another folder, using an absolute path.

I tried this, but doesn't work.

```
git config --get remote.origin.url --path /home/username/myFolder
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
git --git-dir=/home/username/myFolder/.git config --get remote.origin.url
```

Comment: Good, but not complete. The `.git` folder has to be added after `--git-dir` path, like [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1386350/1420197) I edited your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just typed that in from memory, not remembering that it needs the bare repo (the .git folder). Thanks!

Comment: Nice and clean.