# Run `git commit` from another directory

Tags: git

How to run `git commit -m '...'` command from another directory?

I edit my file:

```
vim /home/.../myFile
```

I add it using:

```
git add /home/.../myFile
```

But now, how can I commit the changes?

```
git commit -m '...' ???
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can also use the environment variables `$GIT_DIR` and `$GIT_WORK_TREE` to the same effect as `--git-dir` and `--work-tree`

These are the steps to commit a file when you are in another directory:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/my/directory/.git/ --work-tree=/path/to/my/directory/ add myFile
git --git-dir=/path/to/my/directory/.git/ --work-tree=/path/to/my/directory/ commit -m 'something'
```

Comment: This didn't work for me until I removed the '=' from `--git-dir`. It might need it removed from `--work-tree`, too. Maybe a difference in git versions?

Answer (score 27):

You can use `git -C <path> <command>`.
From https://git-scm.com/docs/git/2.4.4

> git -C <path> commit -m "Some commit message"

Runs as if git was started in <path> instead of the current working directory.

Comment: Not true for git commit.

From help: -C, --reuse-message <commit>

Comment: It is, true ! Actually, `-C, --reuse-message <commit>` is the `-C` option of `git commit`. But there, we use `-C` option of `git`. In other words : `git -C <path> commit ... ` is not the same as `git commit -C <commit> ...`.

Comment: Comments are wrong. You can run `git -C commit <options>` for example  I just run: `git -C syncedConfigs/ commit -m " files`. Great for using with crontab :+)

Answer (score 0):

After commiting everything with the `--git-dir` parameter there where several files deleted from the repo and I had to recover them. 
For me the best solution was in a script to do a `cd` to the other folder and then execute the git commands. Was way less code to write without the parameters in every command.