# Error while calling git commands in subfolder on Windows CMD

Tags: windows, git, cmd

I am trying to call `git fetch` in subfolder while using Windows CMD like this

```
D:>C:\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch path\to\subfolder
```

Then I get error:
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

But when I am in my repository folder everything works fine:

```
D:\path\to\subfolder>C:\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I call git functions in Windows subfolders via CMD?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git --git-dir not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think git fetch can be used to fetch only the changed files in a sub directory. git fetch is normally used to fetch the latest changes from the remote repository and is used like below.

```
git fetch <remote_name> <branch_name>
```

I think What you are doing wrong is providing the sub directory path after "git fetch". I tried the same and got the below error

```
ajbose@L-BLR-00800896 /c/Code/biz/bizdatacollectnodeweb/test (develop)
$ git fetch unit
fatal: 'unit' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I hope this helps.