# git reset --hard when used with git-dir option checks out files in the current directory

Tags: git, git-reset

```
[root@localhost ~]# pwd
/root
[root@localhost ~]# ls
labs  logs  ovpl
[root@localhost ~]# git --git-dir=/root/labs/cse02-programming/.git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 935ca9d apt-get update added to labspec
[root@localhost ~]# ls -l
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 4 root    root    4096 Oct 30 12:54 labs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 Oct 31 17:37 logs
drwxrwxr-x 3 travula travula 4096 Oct 30 12:53 ovpl
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 Oct 31 18:37 python-scripts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    2143 Oct 31 18:37 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 Oct 31 18:37 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 6 root    root    4096 Oct 31 18:37 src
[root@localhost ~]#
```

The problem is: The repository is checked out in the current working directory, as you can see python-scripts, scripts, src and README.txt have beed added here.

How can I force this checkout in the /root/labs/cse02-programming itselff?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git --git-dir not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected)