# specify directory for git pull (not current directory)

Tags: git

I'd like to do update my existing checkout from git, but without being inside of that directory:

```
-sh-3.2$ pwd
/var/lib/gitolite
-sh-3.2$ git clone repositories/visits.git/
Cloning into 'visits'...
done.
-sh-3.2$ cd visits/
-sh-3.2$ git remote -v
origin  /var/lib/gitolite/repositories/visits.git/ (fetch)
origin  /var/lib/gitolite/repositories/visits.git/ (push)
-sh-3.2$ cd
-sh-3.2$ git --git-dir=/var/lib/gitolite/repositories/visits.git/ --work-tree=/var/lib/gitolite/visits/ pull 
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.
-sh-3.2$ cd visits/
-sh-3.2$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
-sh-3.2$ git --version
git version 1.8.2.1
-sh-3.2$
```

I don't really understand `git-dir` and `work-tree`, can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git-dir` should point to the `.git` folder of your local copy (yours points to the *remote* repository you cloned from):

Example:

```
~/tmp> git clone repositories/my-project.git/
Cloning into 'my-project'...
done.
~/tmp> git --git-dir=/Users/jhoffmann/tmp/my-project/.git \
> --work-tree=/Users/jhoffmann/tmp/my-project/ pull
Already up-to-date.
```

---

[Git version 1.8.5](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5fd09df3937f54c5cfda4f1087f5d99433cce527/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L115-L116) introduces `-C` which simplifies this to:

```
~/tmp> git -C /Users/jhoffmann/tmp/my-project/ pull
Already up-to-date.
```

(taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected#answer-20115678))

Comment: thank you, i believe that's exactly what was missing))