# Difference between -C and --git-dir when manipulating repo in git hook

Tags: git, githooks

I am writing a git post-receive hook that will clone a separate repo as part of a deployment. It clones the repo to a certain folder and uses the `-C` option in subsequent git commands to set the directory to that of the checked out repo (as documented in the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html)).

The hook works as expected when run manually from the command line, however when the hook is run by git (ie when a push is received) the command fails with `fatal: Not a git repository: '.'`. When I swap out the `-C` for a `--git-dir` it works.

This is fairly simple to reproduce, create a bare repo `git init --bare` and make an executable hook with the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xe

SOME_REPO_URL=???? # Some repo that is not this one
repopath=/tmp/somerepo

git clone $SOME_REPO_URL $repopath

# 1: This fails when run through the git hook
git -C $repopath checkout -b somebranch HEAD~1

# 2: This works every time
# git --git-dir $repopath/.git checkout -b somebranch HEAD~1
```

Running the script from the command line will work as expected, but when you push to the repo the hook will fail. Commenting `1` and uncommenting `2` will work in both cases.

I can't find any documentation that would indicate that this is intended behaviour - an explanation would be appreciated.

This is git 2.7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It may be helpful to know that the `GIT_DIR` environment variable is set in hooks. You may want to unset it while running your checkout command.

Comment: Worth mentioning if you are stuck using ancient versions of git: the "git -C directory" option was introduced in https://git-scm.com/docs/git/1.8.5 (because in git 1.8.3 I got "Unknown option: -C")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The literal difference between:

`git -C directory git-sub-command ...`

and:

`git --git-dir directory git-sub-command ...`

is that the front end setup program `git` uses an OS-level "change directory to" operation (`os.chdir` from Python, `chdir()` from C, etc) for the first, and sets an environment variable `$GIT_DIR` for the second.  In either case it then locates the sub-command and runs it.  (Note that you can in fact do *both*.)  [This is documented](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html), including the effects of multiple `-C` options and the interaction between `-C` and `--git-dir`.

That, however, just pushes the problem down one level: now you need to know what `git-checkout` (found in the `git --exec-path` directory) does differently with `$GIT_DIR` than it does with the current working directory.  The direct answer is in [the top level `git` command documentation, under the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES section](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html#_environment_variables):

> `GIT_DIR`
>   If the `GIT_DIR` environment variable is set then it specifies a path to use instead of the default `.git` for the base of the repository. The `--git-dir` command-line option also sets this value.

This is where [Jan Krüger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295050/difference-between-c-and-git-dir-when-manipulating-repo-in-git-hook#comment71748526_42295050) comes in.  When you write a Git hook, you must be aware of the fact that Git may set some environment variables for you.  If `$GIT_DIR` is set to a relative path name, and you do not override it, and you do change directories, you will change the way all the various Git sub-commands locate the repository.  Therefore you must either *un*-set it (to get the default `$GIT_DIR`-not-set behavior), or explicitly set it to an absolute path (to preserve it across directory changes), or explicitly set it to the path—relative or absolute—of some other repository, depending on what behavior you *want*.

Note that `--work-tree` sets `$GIT_WORK_TREE`, and there are other similar variables, but—at least in all Git versions to date—`$GIT_DIR` is the only one "pre-set for you" (or "for your annoyance" :-) ) in Git hooks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have upgraded Git since then (2017), make sure to use the latest Git 2.35 (Q1 2022).

In addition to [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42299983/6309), Git 2.35 adds information about the `git rebase -x` command and its historical behavior with environment variables `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`: that offers a valuable context to understand the difference between the `git -C` and `git --git-dir` options in Git.

"[`git rebase -x`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/57f28f40943c077ef1dc11c693d693b1bd6b7f2f/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L536)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--xltcmdgt))</sup> by mistake started exporting the `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variables when the command was rewritten in C, which has been corrected.

See [commit 434e063](https://github.com/git/git/commit/434e0636db102cd89292ea28e8e947fa6e790b23) (04 Dec 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 57f28f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57f28f40943c077ef1dc11c693d693b1bd6b7f2f), 21 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/434e0636db102cd89292ea28e8e947fa6e790b23): do not export `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` for 'exec'
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Altmanninger</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> Commands executed from [`git rebase --exec`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/434e0636db102cd89292ea28e8e947fa6e790b23/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L537)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---execltcmdgt))</sup> can give different behavior from within that environment than they would outside of it, due to the fact that [`sequencer.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/434e0636db102cd89292ea28e8e947fa6e790b23/sequencer.c) exports both `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`.
> For example, if the relevant script calls something like
>
> ```
> git -C ../otherdir log --format=%H --no-walk
> ```
>
> the user may be surprised to find that the command above does not show a commit hash from `../otherdir`, because `$GIT_DIR` prevents automatic `gitdir` detection and **makes the `-C` option useless**.
>
> This is a regression in behavior from the original legacy implemented-in-shell rebase.
> It is perhaps rare for it to cause problems in practice, especially since most small problems that were caused by this area of bugs has been fixed-up in the past in a way that masked the particular bug observed without fixing the real underlying problem.
>
> An explanation of how we arrived at the current situation is perhaps merited.
> The setting of `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` done by [`sequencer.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/434e0636db102cd89292ea28e8e947fa6e790b23/sequencer.c) arose from a sequence of historical accidents:
>
> - When rebase was implemented as a shell command, it would call `git-sh-setup`, which among other things would set `GIT_DIR` -- but not export it.
>   This meant that when `rebase --exec` commands were run via /bin/sh -c $COMMAND they would not inherit the `GIT_DIR` setting.
>   The fact that `GIT_DIR` was not set in the run $COMMAND is the behavior we'd like to restore.
> - When the `rebase--helper` builtin was introduced to allow incrementally replacing shell with C code, we had an implementation that was half shell, half C.
>   In particular, [commit 18633e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18633e1a22a68bbe8e6311a1039d13ebbf6fd041) ("rebase -i: use the rebase--helper builtin", 2017-02-09, Git v2.13.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/098ed50e8a7c581e23cd51b737fb780228fe6f31) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3bc53220cb2dcf709f7a027a3f526befd021d858)) added calls to exec git rebase--helper ...
>   which caused rebase--helper to inherit the `GIT_DIR` environment variable from the shell.
>   git's setup would change the environment variable from an absolute path to a relative one (".git"), but would leave it set.
>   This meant that when `rebase --exec` commands were run via `run_command_v_opt(`...) they would inherit the `GIT_DIR` setting.
> - In [commit 09d7b6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09d7b6c6fab3ad131b71016b61c80d39d532befd) ("`sequencer`: pass absolute `GIT_DIR` to exec commands", 2017-10-31, Git v2.16.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4db47e6a038adcde36ef6305a15d3d7ee49487c) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2ece9dc4de60ead431f7902c273be32c880eede)), it was noted that the `GIT_DIR` caused problems with some commands; e.g. `git rebase --exec` 'cd subdir && '[`git describe`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/434e0636db102cd89292ea28e8e947fa6e790b23/Documentation/git-describe.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe))</sup> ...
>   would have `GIT_DIR=.git` which was invalid due to the change to the subdirectory.
>   Instead of questioning why `GIT_DIR` was set, that commit instead made sequencer change `GIT_DIR` to be an absolute path and explicitly export it via `argv_array_pushf(&child_env,` `"GIT_DIR=%s",` `absolute_path(get_git_dir()`)); `run_command_v_opt_cd_env(`..., `child_env`.argv)
> - In [commit ab5e67d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab5e67d7513ac6efb4c0ee9787aeaa41604c0566) ("`sequencer`: pass absolute `GIT_WORK_TREE` to exec commands", 2018-07-14, Git v2.19.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd3f067815d145e284369d1bfc4fa16aec8d8eab)), it was noted that when `GIT_DIR` is set but `GIT_WORK_TREE` is not, that we do not discover `GIT_WORK_TREE` but just assume it is '.'.
>   That is incorrect if trying to run commands from a subdirectory.
>   However, rather than question why `GIT_DIR` was set, that commit instead also added `GIT_WORK_TREE` to the list of things to export.
>
> Each of the above problems would have been fixed automatically when [`git-rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/434e0636db102cd89292ea28e8e947fa6e790b23/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> became a full builtin, had it not been for the fact that [`sequencer.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/434e0636db102cd89292ea28e8e947fa6e790b23/sequencer.c) started exporting `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` in the interim.
> Stop exporting them now.

---

This adds new elements to the differences and use cases for `git -C` and `git --git-dir`:

- When `GIT_DIR` is set (and exported), it dictates the repository base path for Git operations, which could override or conflict with the intended effect of the `-C` option.
  The `-C` option is meant to change the current working directory for the Git command, but if `GIT_DIR` is set to a specific path, this change might not work as expected.
- However, `--git-dir` is explicitly designed to set or *override* the `GIT_DIR` variable. It directly influences where Git commands look for the repository data, making it more predictable and stable in scripts and hooks, especially when dealing with complex operations like rebase.

The corrections made in Git 2.35 by stopping the export of `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` during `git rebase -x` operations align the behavior of Git commands more closely with what users would expect when using `-C` and `--git-dir`.
These changes make the `-C` option more reliable and consistent, as it would not be unexpectedly overridden by an exported `GIT_DIR` value.

In the context of Git hooks or complex scripts like those involving rebasing, understanding this distinction and the historical changes is important. It helps in predicting how the Git commands will interpret the repository context and behave accordingly.

---

> Does that mean that, since Git 2.35, `GIT_DIR` won't take precedence over the path defined by the `-C` option?

No, the intention is not to change the precedence of `GIT_DIR` over the `-C` option directly.
Instead, the goal is to avoid unexpected environmental exports of `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` that could interfere with the intended operation of Git commands.

In general, when `GIT_DIR` is explicitly set (either as an environment variable or through the `--git-dir` option), it tells Git where to find the repository's `.git` directory. That setting inherently takes precedence over the current working directory or the directory specified by the `-C` option because it directly points Git to the repository's metadata location.

Before the changes in Git 2.35, certain Git commands (like `git rebase -x`) could unexpectedly export `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`, affecting subsequent commands within the same script or hook by imposing a specific repository context. That could lead to confusion and unintended behaviors, especially if `-C` was used to change the working directory context for a command, only to have its effect overridden by an exported `GIT_DIR`.

The modifications made in Git 2.35 aim to prevent the unintentional export of `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` during the execution of certain commands. That change helps making sure the environment does not unexpectedly influence the behavior of Git commands that rely on the current working directory or the directory specified with `-C`.

To your question: after the updates in Git 2.35, `GIT_DIR` will still take precedence if it is explicitly set or determined by Git's environment.
However, the risk of `GIT_DIR` being unexpectedly set (and thus interfering with the `-C` option) is reduced because Git no longer exports `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` in situations where it previously did so without clear intention.
That means that, while `GIT_DIR` continues to define the repository's location, the chances of it unexpectedly overriding the `-C` option due to unintended exports are significantly diminished.

In essence, the update makes sure the use of `-C` for changing the working directory context in scripts and hooks is more reliable and less likely to be unintentionally affected by `GIT_DIR`.

Comment: Does that mean that since Git 2.35 `GIT_DIR` won't take precedence over the path defined by the `-C` option ?