# get all commits between two commits on remote server?

Tags: git, gerrit, between

How to get all commits between two commits on remote server.

Had read the gerrit rest api but not found the effect way, and
don’t want to clone the remote repo locally to get the results, as had lots of repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the gerrit server,

```
ssh <username>@<serverip> GIT_DIR=/path/to/the/repository.git git log commit1..commit2
```

The `username` is the local user used to log in the server, not the username to log in the Gerrit web. For scripts, Python's `paramiko` is recommended.

```
import os
import paramiko

paramiko.util.log_to_file(os.devnull)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(
    hostname='',  # gerrit server ip
    username='',  # server username
    password='',) # password
cmd = 'GIT_DIR=/path/to/the/repository.git git log commit1..commit2'
i, o, e = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
print o.read()
```

Comment: For sake of fullness, besides `GIT_DIR=` syntax it is also possible to use `-C`/`--git-dir` options (the differences between these were answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42299983/7362660))