# Bash script to automatically pull git repo and generate documentation on remote gitolite server does not work

Tags: bash, git, gitolite

On my gitolite I want to automatically generate documentation when a repository is updated. For that I generated a repo-specific hook that calls a bash script which either clones the repository and generates a documentation in it or if the directory already exists it pulls the updates and then generates documentation.

The remote hook gets called however git does not recognize the directory. It for some reason works in `'.'` and doesn't find a .git directory there (but it is there, because it cloned it in a script run before).

```
remote: + /home/git/check_jsdoc.sh kbc
remote: + reponame=kbc
remote: + echo 'Generating documentation for:' kbc
remote: Generating documentation for: kbc
remote: + jsdocdir=/home/git/jsdoc/
remote: + repodir=/home/git/jsdoc/kbc
remote: + test -d /home/git/jsdoc/kbc
remote: + echo '/home/git/jsdoc/kbc exists.'
remote: /home/git/jsdoc/kbc exists.
remote: + test -d /home/git/jsdoc/kbc/.git
remote: + git -C /home/git/jsdoc/kbc pull
remote: fatal: not a git repository: '.'
remote: + documentation build /home/git/jsdoc/kbc/src/App.js -f html -o /var/www/jsdoc/kbc
remote: + exit
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

reponame=$1

echo "Generating documentation for: ${reponame}"

jsdocdir="/home/git/jsdoc/"

repodir="${jsdocdir}${reponame}"

if test -d "$repodir"; then
    echo "${repodir} exists."

    if test -d "${repodir}/.git"; then
        git -C "$repodir" pull
    else
        echo "no .git in ${repodir}?"
    fi
else
    cd "$jsdocdir" || exit 1
    git clone gitolite:"$reponame"
    cd "$jsdocdir" || exit 1
fi

documentation build "${repodir}/src/App.js" -f html -o "/var/www/jsdoc/${reponame}"
```

when I run `check_jsdoc.sh kbc` locally, it works

```
git@gitserver:~$ ./check_jsdoc.sh kbc
+ reponame=kbc
+ echo 'Generating documentation for:' kbc
Generating documentation for: kbc
+ jsdocdir=/home/git/jsdoc/
+ repodir=/home/git/jsdoc/kbc
+ test -d /home/git/jsdoc/kbc
+ echo '/home/git/jsdoc/kbc exists.'
/home/git/jsdoc/kbc exists.
+ test -d /home/git/jsdoc/kbc/.git
+ git -C /home/git/jsdoc/kbc pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 1), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), 394 bytes | 394.00 KiB/s, done.
From gitolite:kbc
   b708b925..aa11c17d  master     -> origin/master
Updating b708b925..aa11c17d
Fast-forward
+ documentation build /home/git/jsdoc/kbc/src/App.js -f html -o /var/www/jsdoc/kbc
```

Comment: Add an `echo "$GIT_DIR"` to see if it's set to some value and trying adding `unset GIT_DIR` before the `git -C` or change `-C` to `--git-dir` as according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42299983/1745001 that variable being set can cause the problem you're seeing when using `-C`.

Comment: Could it  be that there are permission problems, so that `git -C` can not cd to this directory? Instead of using `git -C`, do an explicit `cd "$repodir"` before the `if` , and go back to where you came from with `cd -` after the `fi`. Also, I would check the permissions of `.git`, i.e. do a `ls -ld .git` after you changed into your repodir.

Comment: @EdMorton ´git --git-dir´ solves it. Server was previously running oldold stable that had the old version of git where the -C worked. Now it fails since update (see 2nd answer in the other question)

Comment: @user1934428 nope, git clone runs as the same user as gitolite

Comment: This sort of thing is usually either permissions or environment. Put in debug to make sure the user id is what it was when you ran it, and any environment variables (PATH, etc etc) are what you expect.  Try running it locally with no environment (env - bash) to see what environment it requires.