# How to write a tree object to a directory (outside of the repository)?

Tags: git

I would like to write a git tree into a directory, ie given that output from `git ls-tree`:

```
% git ls-tree -lrt 312735a86fe300861ebf0e6b081616029c2f6b76 

040000 tree ba37a4590a12acdd773e444b06e75ad151150ed2       -    subdir1
100644 blob deba01fc8d98200761c46eb139f11ac244cf6eb5      10    subdir1/test.txt
100644 blob dce813842fd90177bd0fbfd3011797934ee31303      15    test2.txt
```

I want to do:

```
% git some-command 312735a86fe300861ebf0e6b081616029c2f6b76 /tmp/output-dir
```

And have in `output-dir`:

```
tree output-dir
.
├── subdir1
│   └── test.txt
└── test2.txt
```

I imagine I could parse output of `git ls-tree` and then, based on the second column call `git ls-tree` recursively or `git cat-file`. My question is more to know if there is a built-in tool (or an external tool) which allows to do just so?

Comment: Does `git checkout 312735a86...` work? Once you have the checkout you can move it to a directory of your choice. You might also experiment with `--work-tree` (and/or `--git-dir`) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386350/1671066.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) to export the desired tree as a `.tar` archive (it sends it by default to `stdout`) and pipe its output through `tar -x` to unpack the files into the desired directory:

```
git archive HEAD -- subdir1 | tar -x -C /tmp/output-dir
```

Replace `subdir1` with the path inside the repository of the directory you want to export.

Comment: Perfect, it's exactly what I was looking for and not finding! Thanks!

Comment: @code707 indeed, I mixed them up. Fixed now, thank you.