# .git post-receive hook that works when executed in terminal; but not after push

Tags: git, hook

I'm moving from Jekyll to Hugo (awesome!).

My deployment hook has been working fine, but needed a minor update. The previous, and current flow is:

- create a new temporary clone of the source (bare) repo on the same machine
- run the generator
- move the files to the web server directory
- violà, new content

I wrote the shell script and when I execute it in the shell, on the sevrver, it works as expected! Yay!

However, when I make a trivial edit (to trigger the hook) and push, the hook runs, but I get errors from git. I've provided the most keenly odd output from `set -x` below:

```
remote: + rm -rf /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
remote: + mkdir /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
remote: + cd /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
remote: + echo Changing into /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
remote: Changing into /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
remote: + cd /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
remote: + git init
remote: Initialized empty Git repository in /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com/
remote: + git remote add origin file:////home/sgharms/stevengharms.com.git
remote: + git fetch origin
remote: From file:////home/sgharms/stevengharms.com
remote:  * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
remote: + echo XXXXX
remote: XXXXX
remote: + pwd
remote: /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
remote: + git checkout master
remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

But if I run the post-receive script with `sh -x post-receive`...

```
+ rm -rf /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
+ mkdir /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
+ cd /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
+ echo Changing into /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
Changing into /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
+ cd /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
+ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com/.git/
+ git remote add origin file:////home/sgharms/stevengharms.com.git
+ git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 2304, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2222/2222), done.
remote: Total 2304 (delta 72), reused 2245 (delta 42)
Receiving objects: 100% (2304/2304), 118.65 MiB | 42.91 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (72/72), done.
From file:////home/sgharms/stevengharms.com
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
+ echo XXXXX
XXXXX
+ pwd
/home/sgharms/tmp/stevengharms.com
+ git checkout master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin by rebasing.
+ ls .git
branches  config  description  FETCH_HEAD  HEAD  hooks  index  info  logs  objects  refs
...
...
+ git submodule update --init
Submodule 'themes/ananke' (https://github.com/budparr/gohugo-theme-ananke.git) registered for path 'themes/ananke'
```

OK. I have some useful data. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

1. Is the problem the git submodule?
2. `whoami` reports executing at the same user

I'm pretty stumped about what to do next to debug this. I've added all sorts of `ls -al .git` to make sure that the git stuff is always present, and it is. While I'm stymied, I'm also really curious as to what I'm missing here. Any takers?

Comment: A `post-receive` hook runs with environment variable `$GIT_DIR` set. This means Git won't *search* for the Git directory; it expects it to be wherever `$GIT_DIR` points right then. Usually, that's the issue with post-receive hooks. You can unset GIT_DIR or set it to the correct path or use `--git-dir` to override (any of these three will work).

Comment: @torek: Thanks! That was the clue I needed to move forward.

For future seekers:

[Git Dir Not Working as Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected) was the other piece of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For future seekers, Torek's reply put me on the right path. Ultimately I updated the environment variables he pointed to like so:

```
GIT_DIR=$GIT_REPO # the bare-repository with the content in it `~/foo.git`
GIT_WORK_TREE=$TMP_GIT_CLONE # the "working" checkout of the bare repo
```

Comment: Note that if you allow Git to use the main index file (`$GIT_DIR/.index`) to index some other work-tree, be careful that you *only* use that index file to index that particular work-tree. Otherwise you will get other mysterious behaviors when Git thinks the work-tree contains something other than what it actually contains...