# Git: --git-dir shows all files as missing

Tags: git

I have two very similar repositories with the same submodule.
Directories structure:

```
vss
vss/rcv-nginx
rgw
rgw/rcv-nginx
```

When request status from the `rgw` directory (only it!), it shows that all files are deleted. This does not happen for other similar projects.

Here come the git status commands:

```
# On vss
peter@peterpc:~/git/vss$ git --git-dir=rcv-nginx/.git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

# On vss/rcv-nginx
peter@peterpc:~/git/vss$ cd rcv-nginx/
peter@peterpc:~/git/vss/rcv-nginx$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

# On rgw:
peter@peterpc:~/git/rgw$ git --git-dir=rcv-nginx/.git status
On branch feature-rcv-11870_openresty-nginx
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature-rcv-11870_openresty-nginx'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .gitlab/merge_request_templates/Bug.md
        modified:   .gitlab/merge_request_templates/Feature.md
        deleted:    .idea/runConfigurations/Render_Dyrka_Configs.xml
        ...
        (all files marked as missing)

# on rgw/rcv-nginx
peter@peterpc:~/git/rgw$ cd rcv-nginx/
peter@peterpc:~/git/rgw/rcv-nginx$ git status
On branch feature-rcv-11870_openresty-nginx
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature-rcv-11870_openresty-nginx'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

#### P.S.

I've checked out this question ([git --git-dir not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected)) and I know the workaround, but the question remains -- why git behaves differently for the similar projects?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it could happen because of the earlier in this directory only rcv-nginx was a symlink, and later I changed it to be independent, but the Git cache remains.