# Can I git push another directory?

Tags: git

I want to write a batch file to run `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` on a bunch of repositories on my machine so I don't have to do it manually every time. Do git commands have a directory path parameter?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386350/10630900

Comment: You could probably also just `cd` into the directories as part of your batch file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [common option `-C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt) specifies the directory you want `git` to treat as the current directory:

`git -C ~/myGit commit -m "great commit message"`

is effectively equivalent to

`cd ~/myGit ; git commit -m "great commit message"`

except that it doesn't actually change the current directory in the current shell.